# How to properly use input from an Actionlistener event

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, input

I have been learning java for a few months now and I have come across an issue with the way I use input from an actionlistener I have. What happens is that I have a method that will allow the user to input something into the text box and enter it. Once that is done the string will be written to a public static field in my class, which the value of that will be taken from the input method and will return the value, and set the field back to an empty string. It works just fine, but sometimes the console will throw a harmless nullpointerexception. From all the research I have done I figured out that the two threads are causing some sort of confliction, but I haven't really been able to figure out exactly why this is happening or how to fix it.

The error I get sometimes when putting in input.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.text.PlainView.updateMetrics(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.PlainView.lineToRect(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.PlainView.modelToView(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.FieldView.modelToView(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.modelToView(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.modelToView(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.repaintNewCaret(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My Main class
    package hang;

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      GUIHandler gui = new GUIHandler();

      gui.handle();
      gui.person.tries = 6;

      while(true)
      {
          String t = gui.getInput("Put in input\n");
          System.out.println(t);

      }  
  }
}
```

My GUIHandler Class

```
public class GUIHandler implements ActionListener
{
public static String userInput = "";
public static boolean hasinputted = false;

public JFrame frame;
public Container pane;
public PersonComponent person;
public JLabel guessedChars;
public JLabel wordDisplay;

public JTextArea text;
public JScrollPane log;
public JTextField input;
public DefaultCaret bar;

public void handle()
{
    frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setTitle("Hangman");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    pane = frame.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    person = new PersonComponent(); 
    person.tries = 0;
    person.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    pane.add(person);

    guessedChars = new JLabel("placeholder");
    guessedChars.setFont(new Font(null, 0, 20));
    guessedChars.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    pane.add(guessedChars);

    wordDisplay = new JLabel("placeholder");
    wordDisplay.setFont(new Font(null, 0, 20));
    wordDisplay.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    pane.add(wordDisplay);

    text = new JTextArea(8, 40);
    text.setEditable(false);
    text.setFocusable(false);

    log = new JScrollPane(text);
    pane.add(log);

    bar = (DefaultCaret)text.getCaret();
    bar.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

    input = new JTextField();
    input.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    input.addActionListener(this);
    input.setEditable(false);
    pane.add(input);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    if(!input.getText().equals(""))
    {
        userInput = input.getText();
        input.setEditable(false);
        input.setText("");
        hasinputted = true;
    }
}

public String getInput(String message)
  {
    String temp = "";
    this.text.append(message);
    this.input.setEditable(true);

    while(true)
    {
        if(hasinputted)
        {
            temp = userInput + "\n";
            userInput = ""; 
            hasinputted = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return temp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all.  When a Java application is started, the `main` method is loaded within, what is commonly known as, then "main" thread.

Swing uses it's own thread to monitor events and perform it's functionality, which is known as the Event Dispatching Thread.

Swing is a single threaded environment, meaning that it is expected that all modifications and interactions to the UI will be done from within the context of the EDT.

Your whole example is a fluke.  Basically running any kind of long running task or block action (such as loops) within the context of the EDT will cause you application to stall and stop responding to user interactions and paint requests.

Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and pay special attention to the section called [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

The common means by which to achieve what you seem to be trying to do, is use some kind of dialog.  Take a look at [How to make dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details.  Or use an observer pattern, similar to the `ActionListener`

**Example based on comments**

Basically, this example will "wait" until (more correctly be notified when) the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key within the text field.  It will take the value append it to the text area...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class HangManTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HangManTest();
    }

    public HangManTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField field;
        private JTextArea area;

        public TestPane() {
            field = new JTextField(20);
            area = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(field, gbc);
            add(new JScrollPane(area), gbc);

            field.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String text = field.getText();
                    field.setText(null);
                    processGuess(text);
                }
            });

        }

        public void processGuess(String text) {
            area.append(text + "\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no way to just synchronize it?

Comment: The problem is, the `Document` model is normally considered to be thread safe, but the painting isn't.

Comment: You're working in an event driven environment. Something happens, you respond to it. Things don't happen in a linear fashion like a console application. This is how GUI's work

Comment: So no workarounds? How am I going to process input and change the gui correspondingly then? Or is that just impossible?

Comment: The problem is I need to process input from the user in a different thread that will run my application. How would I know when the value inputted needs to be sent to one location or another. Reminder, I'm REALLY new to this stuff so I don't know very much, but I have done my research.

Comment: Curisorty wonders why you need a separate thread to process the input.  However, you would need to use a producer/consumer pattern, whereby the "process" thread would "wait" until you supply it some text to be processed...you would then need away to send that result back to the UI in an appropriate manner

Comment: Okay, lets say I have a hangman game. In this game the user will say, need to guess a letter. In one thread, the code will need to append the textbox to tell the user to guess a letter. If this code just immediately tried to take input from the input box, it would run by as nothing. However the one thread will stop and wait for the user to input something. Now when the user does this, the function I created will be able to take the input from the user and send it to another function that would process the users choice. Do some choices and change the GUI depending if he got it right or not.

Comment: No. What should happen, is the user should type a guess and an event should be raised, which is then processed by the appropriate event handler.  There's no need for multiple threads in this scenario.  Check the updated example

Comment: All I see your program doing is appending the textbox. What I need is to obtain the input and use it elsewhere in the program. You know, I need it to be ran in other code blocks.

Comment: So, take the text from the field and pass it to whatever class/method you need to, just like you would have otherwise. Check update

Comment: @MadProgrammer But lets say I need different kinds of input, say sometimes I need a word to be passed to a field to be stored(Say, when the user makes the word to be guessed), or maybe I want the user to choose some value of their opponent(Modify a different variable in a different class), or maybe I just want to guess a letter and compare it to the  original word that was inputted earlier? If I do it the way you showed me the input would call multiple methods and mess up my program.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be too used to command line programs to really understand event-driven GUI programming. Here's a little lesson.

GUI programming is event driven. This means that a GUI program should wait for the user to do something, then do something in response. This is so important to GUI programming that Java actually does all the work of handling events for you. You seem to be trying to make some sort of subsidiary event loop like you might see in a command line program, where you should be having Java do the event handling.

It seems like what you are trying to do is combine a hangman app with something that takes input from the user and prints it to the console. To do that, just print the message to the console in the `ActionListener`. Then get rid of the `text` text area. If you feel the honest need to have a text area to which the text "Put in input" is appended when the user needs to put in input, you can just set the initial text of the text area to "Put in input" and then append it in the action listener.

After making the above changes, you can delete the `getInput` method and the weird loop from `main`. As a final change, for good measure, you might want to learn about constructors and put the code to make the window in the constructor.

Hope this helps you understand event-driven GUI programming, and program GUIs in java without them having several thousand large bugs which require a large amount of effort to fix.

Comment: I should have stated my main goal. This was just a test to see if I could get the data correctly. I need a way to receive input from the JTextField and process it in the background.